# ng serve command fails with "Cannot read property 'config' of null"

Tags: node.js, angular, github, angular-cli

I am new to Angular, I cloned an Angular project from GitHub (https://github.com/javatutorials2016/shoppersstop) and performed the below commands as mentioned in other stack overflow topic.

```
1. rm -rf node_modules
2. npm install
3. ng serve
```

After running the 4th command I encountered the below Exception. Could someone please help here?

```
    Cannot read property 'config' of null
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of null
        at Class.run (C:\Users\Owner\shopperstop\shoppersstop\shopperstop\node_modules\angular-cli\tasks\serve.js:22:61)
        at C:\Users\Owner\shopperstop\shoppersstop\shopperstop\node_modules\angular-cli\commands\serve.run.js:22:22
        at 
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

I am also providing the ng version command output.

```
    angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.28.3
    node: 8.9.4
    os: win32 x64
    @angular/animations: 7.1.4
    @angular/common: 7.1.4
    @angular/compiler: 7.1.4
    @angular/core: 7.1.4
    @angular/forms: 7.1.4
    @angular/platform-browser: 7.1.4
    @angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 7.1.4
    @angular/router: 7.1.4
    @angular/cli: 7.1.4
    @angular/compiler-cli: 7.1.4
    @angular/language-service: 7.1.4
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to run the second command: `2. npm install --save-dev angular-cli@latest`

If you want, you can install angular-cli globally with the command

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

After that, in your angular project root directory you can launch the commands 2 and 3.

Comment: Just to add to this ... Not only is step 2 not needed, it is *wrong*, so it installed an old beta version of the CLI instead of the correct v7 version.